# Vapor Swift Error "Reference to member 'sqlite' cannot be resolved without a contextual type"

Tags: swift, vapor

On a fresh install of Vapor (from `homebrew`) I call:

- `vapor new Bridge` -> success
- `vapor xcode` -> success
- `y` (asks if I want to open the project in Xcode) -> opens Xcode project
- `vapor --version` -> 3.1.10
- `vapor build` -> fails

The error I get is:

```
[1/3] Compiling App configure.swift
/Users/josh/Applications/Xcode/Projects/Bridge/Sources/App/configure.swift:31:49: error: reference to member 'sqlite' cannot be resolved without a contextual type
    migrations.add(model: Todo.self, database: .sqlite)
                                               ~^~~~~~
[2/3] Compiling App app.swift
```

Version Numbers:

- macOS: `10.15.3 (19D76)`
- Xcode: `11.4 (11E146)`
- Vapor: `3.1.10`
- Swift: `5.2`

Any help figuring out how to solve this error is appreciated! Let me know if I can provide any more information. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I think that mistdon's answer is the best one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `typelias` in `ToDo` class, when you use **Swift 5.2**

```swift
final class Todo: SQLiteModel {

    typealias Database = SQLiteDatabase

    ....
}
```

Comment: Yeah true, thank you! This should be accepted answer

Answer (score 12):

Yeah Vapor 3 experience compilation problems on Swift 5.2
https://forums.swift.org/t/vapor-3-swift-5-2-regression/34764

```swift
migrations.add(model: Todo.self, database: .sqlite)
```

The above code, which compiles fine in Swift 5.1, will now result in the following error:

```
Reference to member 'sqlite' cannot be resolved without a contextual type
```

This can be fixed by using an explicit type instead of leading-dot syntax:

```swift
migrations.add(model: Todo.self, database: DatabaseIdentifier<SQLiteDatabase>.sqlite)
```

Comment: Thanks! That got it running! Just FYI I changed `DatabaseIdentifier<SQLiteDatabase>.sqlite` to `DatabaseIdentifier<Todo.Database>.sqlite`.